# Is the JSON-RPC protocol independent?

Tags: json, protocols, json-rpc

To achieve bidirectional communication between server and client I've designed a simple protocol over JSON (looks [like this](http://pastebin.com/gYp3q4xG)).

The idea was to have such layers:

1. Hardware level – system specific
2. Messaging level – some arbitrary library handles the hardware level to deliver and receive string messages
3. The MyJSONLibrary level – uses library to call an `RPC` or request resource and get response
4. Application level

Until I found out `JSON-RPC` exists, I've had a feeling I'm reinventing the wheel.

But seems like `JSON-RPC` has the layers 2 and 3 combined together, so I can't get a realization for languages L1 and L2, and implement transports for tools A, B, or C. For example, I would like to have python and C# realizations, combined with `ZeroMQ` library as a transport (layer 2), or with websocket transport. Both of tools allow to deliver and receive messages, so the library uses them. Or UDP, or basic HTTP.

**The question is**: does `JSON-RPC` have the layers 2 and 3 combined together? If it is, is there alternatives like I want, or I'd have to stick to my own realizations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the *Transport* layer by "layer 2" and *JAX-RPC runtime* by "layer 3".

---

Quoting from [this changelog](http://www.simple-is-better.org/rpc/#differences-between-1-0-and-2-0) from *JSON-RPC* 2.0 (which is linked in the [official specifications](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification)).

> **Transport independence *[of JSON-RPC 2.0]***
>   JSON-RPC 2.0 doesn't define any transport-specific issues, since transport and RPC are independent.
>   V1.0 defined that exceptions must be raised if the connection is closed, and that invalid requests/responses must close the connection (and raise exceptions).

In fact if you read the specifications<sup>1</sup> you'll find nothing about transport.

**JSON-RPC can be over any transport layer.**

If you want to use an existing library to implement the runtime, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC#Implementations), most implementations use *HTTP* or plain *TCP/IP*<sup>2</sup>.
The process of finding the most suited runtime is tedious and unfortunately I haven't worked with any of them, but since most are open source and tiny<sup>3</sup>, it should't be hard to plug in a new transport layer.

Also since both C# and Python<sup>4</sup> have support for parsing JSON, WebSocket and Socket, reimplementing a minimal *JSON-RPC* runtime should be a matter of a couple of days at most.

---

<sup>1</sup>Which I **strongly encourage to do** as they are very concise and simple.

<sup>2</sup>[Phobos](http://code.google.com/p/blowthemall/downloads/list) is a C++ implementation that abstract the transport layer.

<sup>3</sup>For C# [JayRock](https://atifaziz.github.io/projects/jayrock/) may be promising for customization.

<sup>4</sup>Not sure about Python.